# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

After i include the bootstrap.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

I get followning error in the console: 
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null**

The boots collapse works just fine but the console get spammed this error.
I have included jquery before bootstrap.

Anyone else had this problem before?

Edit:

```
  Tooltip.prototype.show = function () {
var e = $.Event('show.bs.' + this.type)

if (this.hasContent() && this.enabled) {
  this.$element.trigger(e)

  var inDom = $.contains(this.$element[0].ownerDocument.documentElement, this.$element[0])
  if (e.isDefaultPrevented() || !inDom) return
  var that = this
```

this is a snipet from the bootstrap.js script.
It seems the error comes always in the tooltip function in the var inDom line at the documentElement part

Comment: What line of code does the error point to?

Comment: Could you please add a live demo?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You most likely have another tooltip library still in use (like JQueryUI/Tooltip) OR you're trying to attach a tooltip directly to the document element. Please look into your code for something like:

```
$(document).tooltip
```

or something like that, and remove it in order to make things work again. Be sure to review every other **.tooltip()** call you might already have, since they'll most likely not work anymore: you'll need to manually port them to Bootstrap in order to make them work again.

If you want to keep both **Bootstrap/Tooltip** and **JQueryUI/Tooltip** (assuming that's your scenario), you can use **$.widget.bridge** to manually change the JQueryUI tooltip plugin name:

```
// Change JQueryUI/tooltip plugin name to 'uitooltip' to fix name collision with Bootstrap/tooltip
$.widget.bridge('uitooltip', $.ui.tooltip);
```

You need to to this AFTER importing the JQueryUI js file and BEFORE importing the Bootstrap js file: while you're at it I also suggest you to do the same with button/uibutton to solve the exact same problem. The result code will look like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jqueryui.js" />
<script type="text/javascript">
// Change JQueryUI plugin names to fix name collision with Bootstrap:
$.widget.bridge('uitooltip', $.ui.tooltip);
$.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/bootstrap.js" />
```

Then you can just re-route your **$(document).tooltip** call to **$(document).uitooltip** to make everything work.

Alternatively, if you don't find the offending js code and/or you don't want to use $.widget.brige, you can always manually patch **bootstrap.js** to avoid this kind of error. This can be done by replacing the following line (#1384 in bs 3.3.1):

```
var inDom = $.contains(this.$element[0].ownerDocument.documentElement, this.$element[0])
```

with this line:

```
var inDom = $.contains((this.$element[0].ownerDocument || this.$element[0]).documentElement, this.$element[0])
```

Keep in mind, tho, that you'll still have a broken .tooltip() call in your code somewhere.

See also:

http://www.ryadel.com/2015/01/03/using-jquery-ui-bootstrap-togheter-web-page/ (an article I wrote on my blog to better explain the issue)

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14483

http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: I knew exactly what broke my bootstrap setup and you saved me at least an hour of hunting, thanks so much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the element is null before initialising it

i.e.

```
if($('[data-toggle="tooltip"]') != null)
{
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();    
}
```